# Conversion of Hyperspectral images to RGB images

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have a hyperspectral image and i want to convert it into RGB image. I read one paper that uses color matching function, the code is present here (https://github.com/JakobSig/HSI2RGB). I want to know how they have calculated the wavelength field. I am trying it for another dataset, but it is not giving good results?